# I have a problem in writing a program in MATLAB to plot the frequency spectrum of the double tuned amplifier

Tags: matlab, filters, digital-communications, electrical-signal

The equation of the double tuned amplifier is shown below in the image, the plot of the spectrum should look similar the the plot in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried? Can you share where you're stuck?

Comment: my problem is the euation it self, i am not be able to see which parts of it is supposed to be vairables in matlab and which not . its very complicated + how is the 2 small euations supposed to help me in plotting.

Comment: They all need to be "variables" in matlab. You need to find which of these variables are constants (such as `kQ` which you can set to `1` for example), and which is dependent on $f$ (which will make that particular variable an array). [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-tuned_amplifier) gives the answer.

Comment: @Jdip can you please make it more clear to me on hoq can write the code especially that i dont have experience to matlab at all.

Comment: May I ask, why are you trying to code this in Matlab if you have no experience with it?

Comment: i have no experience in coding in general and i need to plot the frequency response of this amplifier, i chose matlab since many people can help me in it.

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** an answer to your question, because I don't know what values the constants $\omega_0, L_1, L_2, g_m, \dots$ should be.

This is just some guidance on Matlab to get you rolling. I've recreated the plot on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-tuned_amplifier) for the Double-tuned amplifier, using the expression provided there:
$$A = A_0 \frac{2kQ}{4Q\delta-i(1+k^2Q^2 - 4Q^2\delta^2)}$$

[image]

Code:

```
% Constants: don't know if these values make sense but it doesn't matter for plotting, since |A| is normalized by A0
gm = 1;
Go = 1;
Gi = 1;
A0 = gm/(2*sqrt(Go*Gi));

% Values for kQ we want to plot as on the wiki page
kQ = [1, 2, 4, 0.5, 0.25];

% x-axis
Qd = (-3:0.01:3);

% Compute A as per wiki page
Ag = [];
for i = 1:length(kQ)
    A = A0 * 2*kQ(i) ./ (4*Qd - 1i*(1+kQ(i)^2 - (2*Qd).^2));
    Ag(i,:) = abs(A)/A0;
end

% Plot
plot(Qd,Ag);
legend('kQ = 1', 'kQ = 2','kQ = 4','kQ = 0.5','kQ = 0.25')
xlabel('Q\delta')
ylabel('|A(\omega)|/A_0')
grid on
```

Comment: that means i need to find the values of my constants to be able to plot the equation i have in the image, your code really helped , but i didint understand why did you write Ag=[ ] before starting the for loop, what does this step do?

Comment: This is just to initialize `Ag` everytime the code is ran. It's not really needed, just less error-prone ;)
And yes, this is just a template, or a starting point so you see how things are set up, but you'd want to have the correct values for your constants. Also, you'd probably want to set the x-axis as $f$ since that's what's in your image plot, which means you'd have something like `f = (-A:step:A)` instead of `Qd = (-3:0.01:3)`, and I'll let you figure out what `A` should be in that case. Feel free to edit your question with what you come up with, I can try and help you when you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you so much , you answer helped me alot and i appreciate the time you gave me to answer my question, i will try to write the code for my equation and will edit my question for you to rate it for me, thank you again.

Comment: No problem. For the future, this strictly speaking is not a signal processing question, but a coding one. These can be asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[Filter Designer App](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filterdesigner-app.html?searchHighlight=filter%20design%20app&s_tid=srchtitle_filter%20design%20app_1)**

Or use [the functions listed here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/digitalfilter.html) to manually  design filters.

Comment: To Peter K : thanks for making it more compact. I agree with you that working links look better with link string hidden. However, sometimes people do not click unless the link is fully available somewhere, so I have this habit of including the full link, so no room for crossed links. Thanks anyway.